# Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017 while accessing MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, remote-host

I have the following exception when running Java app for MongoDB:

```
[localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017 while accessing MongoDB with Java
```

Call stack is follows:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Neither of these names belong to my application. Also I have NO MONGODB server on local host. I am using remote host and setting it later. An exception occurs BEFORE any of my statements concerning Mongo.

**UPDATE**

This is probably some `Spring` provided beans accessing `Mongo`. How to disable them?

My config contains following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3')
    //compile('jai_core:1.1.3')

//  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile('org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.4')
    compile('org.mongodb:bson:3.0.4')

    compile('org.geotools:gt-api:14.2')
    compile('org.geotools:gt-shapefile:14.2')
    compile('org.geotools:gt-geometry:14.2')
    compile('org.geotools:gt-referencing:14.2')
    compile('org.geotools:gt-geojson:14.2')
    compile('org.geotools:gt-mongodb:14.2')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

i.e. I have removed `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and was thinking will use `Mongo` myself...

**UPDATE2**

I found related question: [How to disable spring-data-mongodb autoconfiguration in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747909/how-to-disable-spring-data-mongodb-autoconfiguration-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I was to add exclusion annotation to my main annotated class,

i.e. instead of

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

I should have

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: you are god, bro.

Comment: Martin check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281830/i-cant-exclude-mongoautoconfiguration-in-springboot-kotlin-mongosocketopenexce)

Comment: if above method is not working, you can try this
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/34415014/5300484

Comment: @Dims what does `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})` do?

Comment: @Dims as of today it should be `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: @Dims since `@SpringBootApplication` is already decorated via `@EnableAutoConfiguration` you just have to add that exclusion to `@SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 8):

Try adding

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=hostIpOnWhichMongoIsRunning
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

into `application.properties`.

If Mongo is not running on localhost, this should fix the issue.

Comment: Had a similar issue, setting these properties solved my problem, Thanks !!!

Answer (score 6):

My IDEA suggested that I do this.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the mistake was not to have authorized my development environment. So I allowed connections from any IP (not a good idea for prod env) by adding the rule `0.0.0.0/0`. You add this rule from the `Network Access` section from the atlas dashboard.

Comment: to add to this, had to switch my network due to which the IP address got changed. check if your IP address is added for your MongoDB cluster. (Adding 0.0.0.0/0 will also do.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure. It's kind of not enough information question.

I can say that: Mongo driver by default tries to connect to the local host.
Probably you haven't specified the Mongo host/port.

So you'll have to configure the MongoDB host/port/credentials (if you have those).

Maybe it's network related issue or firewall (try to connect to MongoDB from your machine directly with cli / even running a basic program that uses only mongo driver).

From the stacktrace I don't see any usage of Spring, so more information is required to say for sure.

In general you can analyze the dependencies in Gradle by using `gradle dependencies` command (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception when trying to connect MongoDB with spring-boot.
In my case, I forgot to add the `@Configuration` annotation in the MongoDB Configuration class I created.

After adding this it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the scope(It was Test before)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
<scope>4.2.3</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case mongoDB internal port was not mapped to external. Using command `docker run -p 27017:27017 -d mongo` resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

check your mongo with cmd "mongo" if mongo is deathed follow step
1: open search windown
2: search "services"
3: find MongoDB Service and right click then click start on popup

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the fix is:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers.

In my case this was caused by the Mongo server not accepting connections from my IP. I had to whitelist it in MongoDB console.

Answer (score -3):

It seems your server is not running. 
Also if it running,  it is doing so on a different port.

Comment: My server is running, but not on `localhost`

Comment: Check your address then.

Comment: I checked. It is not `localhost`.

Comment: Try printing out the address. As per the error trace the code is reaching out to localhost.