# Can't connect to MongoDB Database (Prematurely reached end of stream)

Tags: java, mongodb

Well hello,

for some odd reason, I'm getting this strange error

```
    import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
    import com.mongodb.connection.SslSettings;
    import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://Nomar:password@development-uxfw3.mongodb.net/test"))
                .retryWrites(true)
                .applyToSslSettings(builder ->
                        builder.applySettings(SslSettings.builder()
                                .enabled(false)
                                .build()))
                .build());
    }
}
```

I'm 100% sure its supposed to connect but

```
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server development-shard-00-00-uxfw3.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:249)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:235)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:282)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ReadTask.completed(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:575)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:387)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Dec 29, 2018 7:34:38 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server development-shard-00-01-uxfw3.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:249)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:235)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:282)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ReadTask.completed(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:575)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:387)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Dec 29, 2018 7:34:38 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server development-shard-00-02-uxfw3.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:249)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:235)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:282)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ReadTask.completed(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:575)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:387)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

https://hastebin.com/qenogifiri.sql 
I just can't fix this issue I checked for typo's I've checked the IP whitelist I've checked other versions of MongoDB / other types

Comment: try setting the keepAlive

Comment: Nope doesnt work

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35416124/1604068 and this does feel as a duplicate.

Comment: Nope... :c.    .. :c