# Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am having a Spring Boot project using MongoDB. I am trying to connect to MongoDB running on a different machine. My MongoDB is not accessible on localhost but using some private IP accessible to the pod on a specified port. Following is the gradle dependencies file:

```
dependencies {
    // Spring Dependencies
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${rootProject.springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${rootProject.springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:${rootProject.springCloudVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:${rootProject.springCloudVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:${rootProject.springDataMongoVersion}")

    // Application Specific Dependencies
    implementation("com.sun.mail:javax.mail:${rootProject.sunMailVersion}")

    // Apache Dependencies
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:${rootProject.apachePOIVersion}")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:${rootProject.apachePOIVersion}")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text:${rootProject.commonsTextVesion}")
    implementation("org.freemarker:freemarker:${rootProject.freemarkerVersion}")
    implementation("javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:${rootProject.javaxWSVersion}")
    implementation("org.apache.wink:wink-json4j:${rootProject.winkVersion}")
    implementation("jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:${rootProject.jakartaVersion}")

    // Glassfish Dependencies
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:${rootProject.glassfishversion}")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:${rootProject.glassfishversion}")

    // Google Dependencies
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:${rootProject.gsonVersion}")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:${rootProject.guavaVersion}")

    // MongoDB Dependencies
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:${rootProject.mongoDriverVersion}")

    // Tooling Dependencies
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:${rootProject.openapiVersion}")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:${rootProject.lombokVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:${rootProject.springBootVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:${rootProject.micrometerVersion}")

    // Testing Dependencies
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${rootProject.springBootVersion}")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${rootProject.springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run the project I am getting the following error:

```
2023-02-25 14:25:33.710  INFO [,,] 7 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|reactive-streams|spring-boot", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "5.10.147+"}, "platform": "Java/Amazon.com Inc./17.0.1+12-LTS"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, streamFactoryFactory=NettyStreamFactoryFactory{eventLoopGroup=io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup@6d367020, socketChannelClass=class io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel, allocator=PooledByteBufAllocator(directByDefault: true), sslContext=null}, commandListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsCommandListener@72458efc, org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.mongodb.TraceMongoCommandListener@36bc415e], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@6a74d228]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsConnectionPoolListener@349d0836], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.mongodb.TraceAllTypesMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer$AllTypesContextProvider@6a714237}
2023-02-25 14:25:33.993  INFO [,,] 7 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:520) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:488) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:27017
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar!/:4.1.86.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-02-25 14:25:34.064  INFO [,,] 7 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "5.10.147+"}, "platform": "Java/Amazon.com Inc./17.0.1+12-LTS"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='<someuser>', source='<somedb>', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@6a74d228]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[10.1.1.14:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
2023-02-25 14:25:34.196  INFO [,,] 7 --- [10.1.1.14:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:20464}] to 10.1.1.14:27017
2023-02-25 14:25:34.199  INFO [,,] 7 --- [10.1.1.14:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=10.1.1.14:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=130003108}
```

I tried both the approaches from this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415308/exception-in-monitor-thread-while-connecting-to-server-localhost27017-while-acc) but both of it doesn't work. I have the following in my properties file as well:

```
server.port=80
database.url=<someip>:27017
database.username=<someusername>
database.password=<somepassword>
database.database=<somedb>
spring.data.mongodb.host=<somip>
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

Comment: Connection refused means you need to check if mongo DB service it's worked successfully, otherwise the connection still refused.

Comment: I tried ping from pod to that port, it was working fine.