# Error occurred while connecting MongoDB Atlas and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, database, mongodb, database-connection

I'm new to MongoDB and I try to built a simple spring boot CRUD application by replacing MySQL with MongoDB as a database. While running my application after configuring mongo it gives me an Exceptions like MongoSocketWriteException, SSLException.

I checked everything to my knowledge I don't know what else I need to do....So, here i attched my code and errors.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.3)

2023-09-17T14:10:08.790+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] c.e.M.MongoFirstCrudApplication          : Starting MongoFirstCrudApplication using Java 17.0.2 with PID 9504 (D:\Files\SpringBoot\MongoFirstCrud\target\classes started by arul7 in D:\Files\SpringBoot\MongoFirstCrud)
2023-09-17T14:10:08.798+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] c.e.M.MongoFirstCrudApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-17T14:10:11.477+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-17T14:10:11.557+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 64 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2023-09-17T14:10:13.267+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-17T14:10:13.296+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-17T14:10:13.297+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
2023-09-17T14:10:13.705+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-17T14:10:13.711+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4658 ms
2023-09-17T14:10:16.533+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.9.1"}, "os": {"type": "Windows", "name": "Windows 10", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "10.0"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/17.0.2+8-LTS-86"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=majority, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='arul_7', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@63fd4dda, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@1d6751e3]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvHost=arulcluster1.pikx3pg.mongodb.net, srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, requiredReplicaSetName='atlas-xk5epz-shard-0', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=true, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
2023-09-17T14:10:17.161+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [3pg.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-e6uujza-shard-00-00.pikx3pg.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-09-17T14:10:17.271+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [3pg.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-e6uujza-shard-00-01.pikx3pg.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-09-17T14:10:17.274+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [3pg.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-e6uujza-shard-00-02.pikx3pg.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-09-17T14:10:17.485+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-17T14:10:17.628+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [           main] c.e.M.MongoFirstCrudApplication          : Started MongoFirstCrudApplication in 10.052 seconds (process running for 11.393)
2023-09-17T14:10:19.098+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ac-e6uujza-shard-00-00.pikx3pg.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:706) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:580) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:411) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:357) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:77) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:206) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:199) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:159) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:915) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1285) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:577) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2023-09-17T14:10:19.106+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ac-e6uujza-shard-00-01.pikx3pg.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:706) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:580) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:411) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:357) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:77) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:206) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:199) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:159) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:915) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1285) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:577) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2023-09-17T14:10:19.105+05:30  INFO 9504 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ac-e6uujza-shard-00-02.pikx3pg.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:706) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:580) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:411) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:357) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:77) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:206) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:199) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:159) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:915) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1285) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:577) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted`
```

Application.properties file
`spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://arul_7:root@arulcluster1.pikx3pg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority spring.data.mongodb.database = projectmongo1`

Comment: Someone had the same problem in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415308/exception-in-monitor-thread-while-connecting-to-server-localhost27017-while-acc  See if using @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class}) on the top of your Main class will solve your issue or not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You did not provide any code.  You provided logfile details, and you provided a connection string.  But no code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error` error occurs when you haven't allowed your IP address access to the MongoDB Atlas cluster. To allow access to your IP, you need to choose the `Network Access` menu from the left pane in the MongoDB Atlas portal. Then click `Add IP Address` from the `IP Access List` tab that opens up. You can allow access from a specific IP address, a specific CIDR range or use the range `0.0.0.0/0` that would allow access from all IPs.