# Spring boot mongo mongoSocketException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring boot for my rest api but I have a problem about mongo database. Application sometimes throws mongo socket exception and does not execute following codes, when endpoint which needs mongo operation is triggred. I assign true to value of socketkeepalive but it did bot solve my problem. How can I get rid of this problem and can you offer me spring boot mongo db configuration values that are suitable?

By the way, program is working properly. But sometimes it throws this exception.

Thanks

```
INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server **.***.***.***:42015
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Its better to edit your question with exception trace

Answer (score 10):

1. **Spring Boot** has a feature called "auto configuration". In this case, as soon as the Mongo driver is detected on the classpath, the **MongoAutoConfiguration** is activated with default values, which point to *localhost:27017*. If you don't want that behaviour, you can now either configure the properties for **MongoDB** (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb for valid property keys) or disable the MongoAutoConfiguration:

   `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})`
2. **Spring boot** throws this exception when Mongo DB is not running. Please make sure that **Mongodb** is running. It got resolved for me after starting Mongo DB.
3. you can check if mongoDB is running on 27017 is running or not. use this code in your terminal

   `netstat -plntu`

And Please show me your configurations file or properties file.

Comment: Firstly thanks for answer. Actually I connect to remote mongo database not at localhost, I have only three lines mongo configuration these are
spring.data.mongodb.host=**
spring.data.mongodb.port=42015
spring.data.mongodb.database=**

Comment: For the configuration file approach, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49980868/3795043

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue while running mongo inside a docker stack and i just missed the port mapping from 27017 (external) to 27017 (internal), so applying

```
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

to my `docker-compose.yml` file worked for me.