# Remove MongoDB from spring-boot run configurations

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

When I run my application using

> mvn spring-boot:run

my application, which does not use MongoDB, bootstraps some unknown MongoDB Repository. Is there any way to remove this or disable it?

```
2020-06-26 09:45:56.632  INFO 15712 --- [           main] com.cisco.hr.wfpo.WfpoApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-26 09:46:01.083  INFO 15712 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-26 09:46:01.620  INFO 15712 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 504ms. Found 23 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-26 09:46:01.750  INFO 15712 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-26 09:46:01.873  INFO 15712 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 117ms. Found 0 Reactive MongoDB repository interfaces.
2020-06-26 09:46:01.893  INFO 15712 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
```

Comment: Post with similar issue: [How to disable spring-data-mongodb autoconfiguration in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747909/how-to-disable-spring-data-mongodb-autoconfiguration-in-spring-boot).

Answer (score 0):

You have Spring Data MongoDB dependencies that are detected by Spring Data.

if you have below two starters, simply remove them

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```