# Name expected error when using @EnableAutoConfiguration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I was having a similar error to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415308/exception-in-monitor-thread-while-connecting-to-server-localhost27017-while-acc) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747909/how-to-disable-spring-data-mongodb-autoconfiguration-in-spring-boot). I attempted to use @EnableAutoConfiguration to fix the error as was suggested, but IntelliJ gives me an error and says "Name expected". I am unsure what exactly is causing this problem. One possible difference is that I am working in Kotlin and not in Java.
Here is the line that is returning the error.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I also attempted to use the second question's solution of:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

But this had the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess about Kotlin is right. You're trying to use Java syntax in Kotlin.
In Kotlin the first annotation will look like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [MongoAutoConfiguration::class])
```

Check Kotlin documentation about [annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html) for more details if necessary.